# Call a random function from a list of functions

Tags: r

Is it possible to do something like the following in R? The below is in python. I want to execute a random function from a list or Array.

```
my_list = [func_test_1, func_test_2, func_test_3]
random.choice(my_list)()
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example for others to work o

Comment: Something like `my_list <- list(mean, sum, length) ; sample(my_list, 1)[[1]](1:3)` should do (where `1:3` is some test vector you apply functions to). If you just want to call the function, then just `sample(my_list, 1)[[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_funcs <- c("mean", "sd", "max", "min")
x <- rnorm(100)
do.call(sample(my_funcs, 1), list(x))
```

Comment: I think instead of rnorm you meant something like sample(). I tried it but I am getting an error as such :
Error in myfunc(2L) : unused argument (2)

Comment: `x` hear is just a random vector function (`mean`, `sd`, `max` and `min`) takes as the argument, after the function were chosen from `my_funcs` list. In my hands this code works well. Probably you call other functions, so that may produce the error you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you don't have any parameters in your functions.

If all your function are described like "`func_test_*`", you can easily execute a string character with `eval(parse(text=""))` and then use `sample` to get a random number. You just have to do this :

```
int.rnd <- sample(1:length(my_list),1)
eval(parse(text=paste("func_test_",int.rnd,"()",sep="")))
```

Comment: Note that I just use "my_list" to know how many functions you have then don't forget it.

Comment: Why would you do that when you can just call the functions directly from the list?

Comment: If you do not, you just print the function code. You don't call it. You also can use do.call like utubun did.

Comment: You can easily call it by doing `my_list <- list(mean, sum, length) ; sample(my_list, 1)()`. Definitely no need in not `eval` or `parse` which are very bad practices in R or in general.

Comment: I have the following error when I do what you say : `Error : attempt to apply non-function`. Even if I use parameters in brackets because mean/sum/length on an empty vector isn't relevant.

Comment: Sorry you're right you forgot [[]] beetween sample function and brackets.